# Python: Поиск в файле строк из другого файла

Tags: python

Есть 2 txt файла, первый login-pass.txt имеет вид:

```
login1,password1
login2,password2
login3,password3
```

Второй list.txt имеет вид:

```
login1
login2
login3
```

Нужно искать в файле login-pass.txt строки из файла list.txt и при совпадении записывать в другой файл в формате:

```
login,password
```

Нашел здесь подобный скрипт

```
with open('/root/login-pass.txt') as f:
    haystack = f.read()

if not haystack:
    sys.exit("Could not read haystack data :-(")

with open('/root/list.txt') as f:
    for needle in (line.strip() for line in f):
        if needle in haystack:
            print(needle, 'FOUND!!!')
```

Но он при совпадении записывает только строку из списка list.txt т.е. только логины(точнее даже не скрипт записывает, а я запускаю его с выводом в файл, в целом этот пункт меня устраивает), помогите пожалуйста дописать/переписать так, чтобы записывал значение из списка login-pass.txt

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте login-pass.txt и заполните словарь парами (login, pass), разделив строку с ними с помощью split

Поиск ведите в этом словаре, при нахождении выдавайте и ключ поиска, и значение

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/root/list.txt') as f:
    sf = set(f)

with open('/root/login-pass.txt') as f:
    up = [s for s in f if any(map(s.startswith, sf))]

with open('/root/result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(up)
```